# rasbian - iptables `--to` or `--to-destination` unknown option

Tags: linux, networking, debian, iptables, raspbian

I'm trying to run the following commmand on my Raspbian system

`sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i wlan0 -p tcp --dport 2222 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.2.241:22`

iptables says:

```
iptables v1.8.2 (nf_tables): unknown option "--to-destination"
Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.
```

Same issue if I change `--to-destination` to `--to`.

I'm fairly new to `iptables` etc, and I haven't been able to track down the issue with internet search.

I understand that at some point `iptables` is changing into "nf_tables"? Has this already happened in Raspbian? Is that the source of my problem?

Comment: I have the same issue on my raspbian with --dport. I think I am going crazy.

Answer (score 1):

That exact command works on my RPi with *Raspbian 10 Buster*.

Perhaps you've got a corrupted installation with some missing files? Or some non-standard settings?

Replace the SD card with a fresh new Raspbian system and try again. It should work, the command is correct.

Comment: What kernel version are you running?

Comment: It's very strange. I have 3 pi's, all doing slightly different things, but they were burned using the same image about 6 months ago... On one system if I run `sudo /usr/sbin/iptables-legacy` it complains that `--to-destination` is not found. The other two complain that `--dport` is not found. The other two systems both also complain with this error `iptables v1.8.2 (legacy): can't initialize iptables table filter: Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.` ... what the heck is going on here?

Comment: Is there any way to reinstall iptables? The only difference I can think of is the origional system I was working on probably has the package iptables-persistant installed, whereas these two others probably do not

Comment: @user3728501 my kernel is `4.19.97-v7l+`, not sure what’s wrong with yours.

Comment: Mine is the same - but get this. I rebooted and now it works. ...  a complete wtf moment from me I think ?

Comment: @user3728501 on the bright side - it works now :) BTW It may be a stretch too far but a broken firewall and inexplicably behaving commands are sometimes a sign of a compromised system. Especially if it suddenly goes away after a reboot. Not sure if that can apply in your case, just saying that it’s a possibility.

Comment: That's useful info. Is there any way to know if my system has been comprimised? I guess it could potentially be that. port 22 is open to the external world.

Comment: There are forensic tools that can be used but it’s much easier to just rebuild it and secure it properly before connecting to the outside world.

Comment: Are there any writeups with recommendations? Obviously things like strong passwords, and keep apt updated, but other than that?